# How can I create Instagram like profile page in Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm currently creating iOS app and having a problem with the usage of UICollectionView. 
When you create Instagram-like profile page, the simple way of doing is, I guess, having a UIView on top of VC which contains user data and having a collectionView below that. But in my case, problem comes up when I scroll down collectionView. it doesn't scroll all of VC but only collectionView area scrolls down. And I have no idea how can I implement the scroll action correctly.
Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a simple. I just had to create the upper view as UICollectionReusableView and add to CollectionView as a UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader.

Comment: Do you know how to do this with UITableViews?

Comment: I did what you suggested, but for some reason, the header dissapears after scrolling

Comment: @AbedNaseri how about making horizontal swipe between posts and tags?